# Retrieve list of products of a given Category, based on latest snapshot?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have  a list of products and a list of categories.
Each product is in some categories in a specific time, 
i.e. from time to time, we change products in categories.

So, to keep a log, I have a table `Product_Category` with 3 fields:

```
category_id [INT], product_id [INT], snapshot_date [DATE]
```

Where `snapshot_date` is the last update time of the category with all its products

I want to select all products ids, for a given category_id (assume `category_id = 1`), where I want only the products for the last snapshot of this category

For example assume data in Product_Category:

```
+-------------+------------+---------------+
| category_id | product_id | snapshot_date |
+-------------+------------+---------------+
|      1      |      1     |   2015-01-01  |  -----> old snapshot ignore it
|      1      |      2     |   2015-01-01  |  -----> old snapshot ignore it
|      1      |      3     |   2015-01-01  |  -----> old snapshot ignore it
|      1      |      1     |   2015-01-07  |  -----> last snapshot for category 1, this is my target
|      1      |      5     |   2015-01-07  |  -----> last snapshot for category 1, this is my target
|      1      |      7     |   2015-01-07  |  -----> last snapshot for category 1, this is my target
|      2      |      5     |   2015-01-01  |  -----> another category, old snapshot, ignore it
|      2      |      7     |   2015-01-07  |  -----> another category, last snapshot, ignore it
|      2      |      3     |   2015-01-07  |  -----> another category, last snapshot, ignore it
+-------------+------------+---------------+
```

Given `category_id = 1`, I want the result to be

```
+------------+
| product_id |
+------------+
|      1     |
|      5     |
|      7     |
+------------+
```

Here is what I did till now:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM Product_Category
WHERE category_id = 1
      AND snapshot_date = (
          SELECT MAX( snapshot_date )
          FROM Product_Category
          WHERE category_id = 1
      );
```

Is there a better solution tha doing nested selects ?
PS, I am using MySQL if the answer may be different based on RDBMS

Comment: Yup, one product can exists in multiple categories, for example 'treadmill' product is in 'fitness devices' category and 'electronic devices' category, it is intended in the simplified exposed data

Comment: . . I get it.  Your query is fine.

Comment: Isn't nested select very bad in performance ? O(n^2) ? That's why I am searching for an alternative

Comment: you could use a join but I doubt it will be faster (you would still be doing 2 selects on the same table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be fine.  However, some versions of MySQL might run the subquery for each row processed in the outer query.  The solution to that is to move the subquery to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT pc.product_id
FROM Product_Category pc JOIN
     (SELECT category_id, MAX( snapshot_date ) as maxsd
      FROM Product_Category
      WHERE category_id = 1
      GROUP BY category_id
     ) pcmax
     ON pc.category_id = pcmax.category_id and
        pc.snapshot_date = pcmax.stampshot_date;
```

Most databases (including I believe the more recent versions of MySQL) would only execute the subquery once in your query.  However, this structure guarantees that the subquery is only executed once.